# Why does koa use generator function as middleware without 'yield' keyword?

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I had a bit experience in expressjs. Basically you implement a function with req, res, and next.

```
function myMidWare (req, res, next) {
   // do mid ware work

  next() // call next to trigger next middleware 
}
```

Later on, I see code for koa using nodejs 8.

here is a piece of code from [here](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000008991937):

```
var sha1 = require('sha1');
// define a Koa middle ware
module.exports = function(opts){
    return function *(next){
        var token = opts.token;
        var signature = this.query.signature;
        var nonce = this.query.nonce;
        var timestamp = this.query.timestamp;
        var echostr = this.query.echostr;
        var str = [token,timestamp,nonce].sort().join('');
        var sha = sha1(str);
        this.body = (sha === signature) ? echostr + '' : 'failed';
    };
}
```

below is app.js that is using Koa middle ware defined above

```
// app.js - using the Koa middle ware
'use strict'

var Koa = require('koa');
var wechat = require('./wechat/generator');

var config = {
    wechat:{
        appID:'...',
        appSecret:'...',
        token:'...'
    }
};

var app = new Koa();
app.use(wechat(config.wechat));
app.listen(8080);
```

Then, I learned from MDN that [iterator function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) . function* declaration should have 'yield' key word, but I can't find 'yield' keyword in the generator function definition in above code.

**Question:**

1. Why they define a generator function without 'yield' keyword?
2. How does koa control middle ware executing sequence using generator function?

Comment: yield is like a pseudo await.

Comment: @Jonasw I understand await keyword. Why this middleware needs iterator function instead of a normal function?

Answer (score 1):

With the new await syntax, we can stop a function execution in the middle, await something (e.g. a databse call), and then continue with the execution:

```
await dbcall();
await next();
```

In pre ES7 async code results in callback and promise hells, the only thing that supports yielding inbetween is a generator function. It creates an easy way to delegate actions and recontinue execution if they finish. A small example would be:

```
function asy(func){
  var gen = func();
 (function next(v){
   var res = gen.next(v);
  res.value.then(v => res.done || next(v));
 })();
}
```

So you can do:

```
asy(function* (){
  var v = yield Promise.resolve("test");
  console.log(v);
});
```

---

The whole principle is explained in depth [here](https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-started-with-koa-part-2/)

So to finally answer your question: if the function does not need to yield, theres no need to yield ;)